# How to create an email reminder in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a sharepoint task reminder using sharepoint 2013.
I have implemented the following code, but is not working as expected.

What am I doing wrong ? Please see the attached screenshot.

[image: Sharepoint task reminder]

**EDIT:**

I tried a different approach, but still no result.

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

I setup the today variable, I add 7 days to it and output to due date. Then I create a loop while today is less than due date.

I receive no emails with this.

Comment: What is it actually doing and what is the expectation?

Comment: I get only the first email for the task creation and I want to get emails as a reminder once every day until the task will be closed, so when the Current Item:Confirm Offer will be on Yes and we will move to the next stage. I set it up as 10 minutes just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Site Workflow for this.

Site Workflow can be used to set reminders on a list.

Comment: I have found something similar to this, but I do not know when the workflow will end. It might end in 7 weeks from when is started. That is why in each stages i have assigned a task to the creator of the workflow, and for each stage i want to set up a reminder that will tell him to complete that stage and move to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom solution deployed on your SharePoint site, you can use a custom timer job and schedule it to run daily. This timer job will check that whether the assigned task to assignee is completed or not and if task is not completed then trigger an email to the assignee.